# Extracting and Counting TriGrams from DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, nltk

I have a dataframe created through combining multiple PDF's imported using PyPDF2. The frame looks like this :

**combined_df**

```
Index    Title        Page
1        Title 1      Text from page 1
2        nan          Text from page 2
3        nan          Text from page 3
4        Title 2      Text from page 1
5        nan          Text from page 2
```

The rows on the 'Page' column contain all the text from each page of the PDF, so can be quite large. I am trying to take the 'Page' column and sum up the trigrams. I am using the following code, however have succeeded in extracting the individual letters, and not words.

```
combined_df['page'] = combined_df['page'].astype(str)    

trigram_measures = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()
finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_documents(combined_df['page'])

finder.nbest(trigram_measures.pmi, 100) 
s = pd.Series(combined_df['page'])
ngram_list = [pair for row in s for pair in ngrams(row, 3)]
counts = Counter(ngram_list).most_common()

trigram_ df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(counts, columns=['gram', 'count'])
```

This gives me the following output :

```
Index    Gram               Count
0        (' ', 't', 'h')    17793
1        ('t', 'h', 'e')    15882
2        ('h', 'e', ' ')    11255
3        ('i', 'n', 'g')    8846
4        ('e', 'n', 't')    8688
5        (' ', 'i', 'n')    8665
```

I suspect this is something simple that I am doing that is causing my loop to not recognise spaces between words, can anyone help?

**Updated Code**

```
combined_df['page'] = combined_df['page'].astype(str)    

trigram_measures = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()
finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_documents(combined_df['page'])
finder.nbest(trigram_measures.pmi, 100) 

s = pd.Series(combined_df['page'])
trigram_df = s.apply(lambda x: Counter(ngrams(x.split(), 3)).most_common())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `split` the strings to turn the `strings` into a `list`. Otherwise `ngrams` will be using the input string as the iterable over which to find 3-grams:

```
s.apply(lambda x: Counter(ngrams(x.split(), 3)).most_common())
```

---

From this toy example:

```
0    [((Text, from, page), 1), ((from, page, 1), 1)]
1    [((Text, from, page), 1), ((from, page, 2), 1)]
2    [((Text, from, page), 1), ((from, page, 3), 1)]
3    [((Text, from, page), 1), ((from, page, 1), 1)]
4    [((Text, from, page), 1), ((from, page, 2), 1)]
Name: Page, dtype: object
```

---

**Update**

To find the most common 3-gram on the entire column you could use:

```
from itertools import chain

out = s.apply(lambda x: Counter(ngrams(x.split(), 3)).most_common(1))
Counter(chain.from_iterable(out)).most_common(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yatu! 

This gives me a dataframe with each row split into 3grams (representing each pdf page). This is great, but is there a way to combine all the 3grams from the entire dataframe in order to show the most common? 

I have updated my original post with the new code. Thanks for your help